# how to use SWF Symbol as up,down,up etc skin in Skin file?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, themes, skinning, flash-builder

How can we embed the over,up,down etc skins defined as sybols in a .swf file... i mean in skin file how can i specify those symbols to be used as up,over,down skins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS file:

```
ComponentClass {
   upSkin:Embed(source="Assets.swf",symbol="MyUpSkin");
   overSkin:Embed(source="Assets.swf",symbol="MyOverSkin");
}
```

Comment: for spark button control,
s|Button
{ 
}

IN CSS  i am only able to specify its skin class... so is there any way that i make skin usin SWF Symbols, or in CSS specify those symbols just like i do for MX Controls.

Comment: i am in urgent need of building SKIN from the SWF Symbols for   SPARK CONTROLS Plz help me out